# SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead,

Tags: python, pandas

THIS IS MY CODE, When i'm trying to run it I get this error " SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead "
PLEASE HELP. What Should I do ?
temp_df is a copy of train_df which is a slice of the main dataframe ( Paris_AirBNB )

```
    np.random.seed(1)
    
    paris_listings = pd.read_csv("paris_airbnb.csv")
    paris_listings = paris_listings.loc[np.random.permutation(len(paris_listings))]
    stripped_commas = paris_listings['price'].str.replace(',', '')
    stripped_dollars = stripped_commas.str.replace('$', '')
    paris_listings['price'] = stripped_dollars.astype('float')
    train_df = paris_listings.iloc[0:6000]
    test_df = paris_listings.iloc[6000:]
    
    
    def predict_price(new_listing):
        temp_df = train_df.copy()
        temp_df['distance'] = temp_df['accommodates'].apply(lambda x: np.abs(x - new_listing))
        temp_df = temp_df.sort_values('distance')
        nearest_neighbor_prices = temp_df.iloc[0:5]['price']
        predicted_price = nearest_neighbor_prices.mean()
        return predicted_price
    
    
    test_df['predicted_price'] = test_df['accommodates'].apply(lambda x: predict_price(x))
    test_df.head()
```

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple ways to "solve" this issue. Currently, when you take `test_df = paris_listings.iloc[6000:]`, that is indeed a slice of the original dataframe, so when you are later modifying it by adding a new column, it is unclear to Pandas whether that would/could also be modifying the original dataframe (most likely it wouldn't).

**Solution 1**

Make sure that `test_df` is actually a `copy` of `paris_listings`, by specifying:
test_df = paris_listings.iloc[6000:].copy()

Depending on the size of the data, this could end up duplicating your data in memory and taking up space unnecessarily.

**Solution 2**

Ensure that you always use `.loc` or `.iloc` notation, as suggested in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy). That means using:

```
test_df.loc[:, 'predicted_price'] = test_df.loc[:,'accommodates'].apply(lambda x: predict_price(x))
```

As well as inside the function:

```
temp_df.loc[:, 'distance'] = temp_df.loc[:, 'accommodates'].apply(lambda x: np.abs(x - new_listing))
```

**Solution 3** (not really a solution, but you can)

You can ignore and/or suppress the warning, if you think it's not really a problem and if you would be ok if the program actually modifies your original dataframe, given that it's a new column you're adding. Not recommended, as this can be unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

```
temp_df.loc[:, 'distance'] = temp_df.loc[:, 'accommodates'].apply(lambda x: np.abs(x - new_listing))
```

Maybe modify the corresponding place into this? You can have a try.